# Why are multiple hashmaps being populated instead of 1 when storing hashmaps inside of a hashmaps?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm using the spigot api in Java to create a plugin (for minecraft) and to make cooldowns I've stored hashmaps inside of a hashmap.
The outer hashmap is:

```
Map<String, Map<UUID, Long>> itemCooldowns = new HashMap<>();
```

When I try to add to a certain map inside the outer map (the problem isn't the cdId, I've checked):

```
itemCooldowns.get(cdId).put(p.getUniqueId(), System.currentTimeMillis() + cdTime);
```

It adds it to the correct map (with the key totem_of_storms_1) and also to another map (with the key totem_of_storms_2).

Another example of when this happens is if cdId is totem_of_time_2 it will add to totem_of_time_1 as well.

I have checked that it is this line that is adding to multiple hashmaps `itemCooldowns.get(cdId).put(p.getUniqueId(), System.currentTimeMillis() + cdTime);` but I have no idea why

Comment: This means that multiple keys of your outer Map are associated with the same `Map<UUID, Long>` instance.

Comment: ok, thanks i'll look into that

Comment: Try to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Most likely the same inner map is present as the value of multiple keys in the outer map.

Comment: Eran and gscaparrotti thanks for the help, you were right. If u want, post an answer and ill set it as correct.

Comment: @scruffyboy13 If they do not write an Answer, know that on Stack Overflow you are welcome and encouraged to write and accept your own Answer to your own Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an object referenced in multiple place, modifying it from one access point will make it visible from any other access point.

---

A very simple example can be done with a `List`

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> b = a;

System.out.println(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.set(1, 123);
System.out.println(b); // [1, 123, 3, 4]
```

---

Your case is a bit more complex with stays the same (I replaced `UUID` by `String` for visibility)

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> items = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Long> m1 = new HashMap<>(Map.of("a", 123L));
itemCooldowns.put("a", m1);

Map<String, Long> m2 = new HashMap<>(Map.of("b", 456L)); // put m2 on 2 different keys
items.put("b", m2);
items.put("c", m2);

System.out.println(itemCooldowns); // {a={a=123}, b={b=456}, c={b=456}}

items.get("c").put("123", 789L);
System.out.println(items);         //{a={a=123}, b={b=456, 123=789}, c={b=456, 123=789}}

/* Modifying from access point 'c' make it also accessible from access point 'b'
items -> a=m1
      -> b=m2
      -> c=m2
```